# Greek font for latex

Tags: fonts

I am now editing a book with some math expressions with Greek letter. I was asked to use the font as following. However, I cannot find the right font. What is the name of this font and how could I use it in Latex (I am afraid the 2nd would no longer a problem once I know the name of it )?
Here comes the picture of the font:
[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}`.

Comment: This comment is not about a greek font, but you can know what math symbol you want by handwriting it in [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). It's very easy and fast!

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
```

[image: psi]